# How to show loading image during action method post and hide it when post is done?

Tags: jsf

i am using **jsf 1** (no ajax support), and i am using **action methods** with **commandLink** and **commandButtom** and i was wondering how to show loading image during action postback to server and hide it when server side processing (postback) is done.

please advise.

Comment: The following will provide you with a solution: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx , you can adopt it to your needs, take what you need and ignore all the else.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide for an `onclick` of `<h:commandButton>` to show your loading indicator, like in:

```
<h:commandButton ... onclick="showLoadingIndicator()" />
```

Alternatively, you may use `onsubmit` of `<h:form>`:

```
<h:form ... onsubmit="showLoadingIndicator()" />
```

This will call your JavaScript function when the button is clicked, or the form is submitted, in which you are supposed to visualize your loading indicator.

Comment: i know the onclick and onsubmit sorry i was not very clear in my question, but how to hide the loading image when server side processing (postback is done).

Comment: There's no means of any ajax (asynchronous request processing), so the complete page is just synchronously refreshed and brought back in its default state. You don't need to manually stop the progress. Have you *tried* it anyway?